# How to add an item to the text selection popup menu?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, menu-items

When the user marks some text (inside of an `EditText`, `WebView`...) a floating text selection popup appears, where apps can add custom items. Can someone please give me an example, how to add an item to this popup menu which makes an intent and transfers the selected `String` to my activity.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

This blog tutorial will show you how: https://medium.com/google-developers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999

Basically, in your `Manifest` file, add `PROCESS_TEXT intent filter` to the activity that will handle the text shared from popup menu.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ProcessTextActivity"
    android:label="@string/process_text_action_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, you would process that text in your `Activity` like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.process_text_main);
  CharSequence text = getIntent()
      .getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT);
  // process the text
}
```

Comment: Is the context menu of text selection something of the OS itself, or of something else? Can it be modified by the app that hold the EditText?

Comment: The way u did is working great but I am using navigation component with fragments, now i only have one activity. I need to add multiple option in floating text selection menu. How to approach this as i don't want to create empty activities ?

Comment: But how can I use it within Jetpack Compose? I've tried to create an activity class that extends `ComponentActivity`, but it just invokes a White screen.