# What is the name of Google Translate's (android) functionality, that with the app I can search for any highlighted text?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I would like to know how can I implement similar functionality in my app or at least what's its name or how can I search for it. I can highligh any text in any app, a little list comes up, and shows me that the text can be "used within tha Google Translates app" - in this case the text will be translated. Is this implemented by broadcast receiver? Or something else?
[Here](https://prnt.sc/rhduyn) is a picture. "Fordítás" means "translate" in my language.

Comment: if you're asking what a feature on android is called, it's probably off-topic here. if you're asking how to implement it, that's too broad :)

Comment: Without mentioning that you are trying to build an app, feature identification is a bit more on topic at: https://android.stackexchange.com/ which is for end-users of Android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an item to the text selection popup menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632908/how-to-add-an-item-to-the-text-selection-popup-menu)