# Add more options on text selection Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

[image: screenshot]

While selecting text in an `EditText`, we normally get 3 options - Copy, Paste, Select All. But if we select text on applications like WhatsApp, Slack, etc we have extra added options: Bold, Italic, etc.

How do I add more options while selecting text in an EditText?

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632908/how-to-add-an-item-to-the-text-selection-popup-menu